# Shortcut for brackets "[ ]" on Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Hi all I would like to know if it's possible to add or change a keyboard shortcut to make brackets "[ ]". They are available by doing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd> but I would like to change it or add one to just do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>(</kbd> for example at least one thing faster because in programming I will win a lot of time (in my opinion) haha. Thanks in advance ciao!

(I'm on MacOS Sierra)

Comment: You probably need to tell us what nationality your keyboard & layout are. On English layouts they have their own keys. https://support.apple.com/HT201794

Comment: Oh sorry I'm french and with the 'azerty' keyboard we need to do Alt + Shift + ( and I'd just like to do Cmd + ( or anything easier :')

Comment: OK, probably [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html) though software recs are frowned on as answers, so I'll just leave it here ;)

Comment: Mmh ok but it's not really what I want because with KE I can just replace one key with another and I want to replace one shortcut with another but it will do if I can't find a better solution. Thank you guy !

Comment: Finally it's not what I'm looking for... Thanks anyway ! :')

Comment: Since most programming happens in english anyway, it might be worth to consider adding the U.S. keyboard in the settings and using a shortcut to switch between them (https://discussions.apple.com/message/17760654#message17760654). However, that would be probably a bigger challenge, than just getting used to press 3 buttons simultaneously ...

Comment: Yes, but press 3 buttons is so fucking loooooong.... I'm just trying to save time ^^ Any solution is good to take hehe !

Answer (score 11):

On latest MacBook Pro it works like this:

- <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> : `[`
- <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> : `]`
- <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> : `{`
- <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> : `}`

I would love to have them as shortcuts on the touch bar together with the pipe-symbol `|` (= <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>) and the backslash `\` (= <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>)!

Comment: Honestly, I have the last M1 Pro, I still can't understand why it doesn't appear on the keyboard. Is it something bad ? I am really curious.

Answer (score 3):

**alt** + **8** worked for me in MacBook Pro and I believe for programming it's convenient.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for me :/

Answer (score 2):

In my case using macbook pro 2019 13-inch azerty

```
option + shift + ( : [
option + shift + ) : ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the easiest way to write square braket, braces and perenthesis by mac type keypad. alt+shift= {, only alt= [ and shift= (

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please expand your answer to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for this myself, and I think there's not one specific answer to this question. I think it depends on the keyboard layout (Language). I have MacBook Pro 2018 with Norwegian keyboard, and I found that the following key combinations works for me:

Option + 8 = [
Option + 9 = ]
Option + Shift + 8 = {
Option + Shift + 9 = }